# MySQL Select top N Cheapest product from each category

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Here is mySQL **product** table

```
+--------+-------+-----+
|Product | Price | Cat |
+--------+-------+-----+
| iPhone | 1     | 32  |
| Samsung| 2     | 32  |
| Dell   | 1     | 21  |
| HP     | 2     | 21  |
| RedMi  | 3     | 32  |
| Acer   | 3     | 21  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

Required Result top 2 cheapest in each category:

```
+--------+-------+-----+
|Product | Price | Cat |
+--------+-------+-----+
| iPhone | 1     | 32  |
| Samsung| 2     | 32  |
| Dell   | 1     | 21  |
| HP     | 2     | 21  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

I tried `select * from products group by cat order by price` but it returns only first cheapest price product. I need top 2 cheapest.

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY cat`.  Wow....

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables to get the ranking of the products for each category:

```
SET @rn := 0;
SET @cat := 0;
SELECT product, price, cat FROM (
  SELECT @rn := case 
    WHEN @cat = cat then @rn + 1 
    ELSE 1
  END AS rn, product, price, cat,
  @cat := cat  
  FROM products 
  ORDER BY cat, price 
) t
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY cat, rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/irCt36b5eZ2Ty6eamjcpJa/0).
For MySQL 8.0+ there is [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT product, price, cat
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY price) rn  
  FROM products
) t 
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY cat, rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/irCt36b5eZ2Ty6eamjcpJa/1).
Results:

```
| product | price | cat |
| ------- | ----- | --- |
| Dell    | 1     | 21  |
| HP      | 2     | 21  |
| iPhone  | 1     | 32  |
| Samsung | 2     | 32  |
```

Comment: This seems like procedure, any simple query :)

Comment: This is not a simple query that uses variables. This is the way to simulate ranking in MySql prior to version 8.0. But if your version is 8.0+ try the other query in my answer.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY

Comment: hmmm, my mysql server version is I guess is older :(

Comment: Most probably your MariaDB version does not support window functions.

Comment: anyother solution? I run first query and it took 46 sec with no result in phpmyadmin

Comment: About time efficiency you can set an index for `Cat` (if there isn't one). About other more efficient solutions for this case no, I can't think of one.

Comment: btw, thanks for the solution. I am trying to figure out solution using your help :)

Comment: @forpas . . . The variables version is not correct, even if it seems to work in many cases.  MySQL specifically warns that the evaluation of expressions in a `select` follows no guaranteed ordering, so you should not assign a variable in one expression and use it in another (such as you do with `@cat`).

Answer (score 0):

```
select type, variety, price
from fruits
where price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type)
   or price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type
      and price > (select min(price) from fruits as f2 where f2.type = fruits.type));
+--------+----------+-------+
| type   | variety  | price |
+--------+----------+-------+
| apple  | gala     |  2.79 | 
| apple  | fuji     |  0.24 | 
| orange | valencia |  3.59 | 
| orange | navel    |  9.36 | 
| pear   | bradford |  6.05 | 
| pear   | bartlett |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing     |  2.55 | 
| cherry | chelan   |  6.33 | 
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> Quoted from a comment under @forpas answer
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(PARTITION BY –

You also could try to simulate the results of

```
SELECT product, price, cat
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY price) rn  
  FROM products
) t 
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY cat, rn
```

More or less with the queries below, as your MariaDB seams not to be supporting window functions.

> But try to upgrade to a MariaDB version to which does supports window
>   functions.

**Query**

```
SELECT  
   products1.Product
 , products1.price
 , products1.cat 
FROM 
 products products1
LEFT JOIN
 products products2
ON
 products1.cat = products2.cat
AND 
  products1.price >= products2.price
GROUP BY 
   products1.Product
 , products1.cat
 , products1.price
HAVING
 COUNT(*) <= 2
ORDER BY
   products1.Product ASC
 , products1.cat ASC
 , products1.price ASC
```

**Result**

```
| Product | price | cat |
| ------- | ----- | --- |
| Dell    | 1     | 21  |
| HP      | 2     | 21  |
| iPhone  | 1     | 32  |
| Samsung | 2     | 32  |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/irCt36b5eZ2Ty6eamjcpJa/7)

**Note:** this query requires

`INDEX(Product, Cat, price), INDEX(Cat, price)`

This index requirement might be a bit to much as that would make the index file (much) larger then the table file. Assuming `Product | Price | Cat` are the only columns..

If Product is unique within a cat and price group you should be able to get away with.

**Query**

```
SELECT  
   (SELECT
      products_inner.Product
    FROM
     products products_inner
    WHERE
     products_inner.cat = products1.cat 
    AND
     products_inner.price = products1.price 
   ) AS "Product"
 , products1.price
 , products1.cat 
FROM 
 products products1
LEFT JOIN
 products products2
ON
 products1.cat = products2.cat
AND 
  products1.price >= products2.price
GROUP BY 
   products1.cat
 , products1.price
HAVING
 COUNT(*) <= 2
ORDER BY
   products1.cat ASC 
 , products1.price ASC
```

**Result**

```
| Product | price | cat |
| ------- | ----- | --- |
| Dell    | 1     | 21  |
| HP      | 2     | 21  |
| iPhone  | 1     | 32  |
| Samsung | 2     | 32  |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/irCt36b5eZ2Ty6eamjcpJa/8)

**Note:** this query requires only

`INDEX(Cat, price)`

But on the other side it is using a corelated subquery against the grouped record to get the product which might optimize badly.

Note the shorter ANSI/ISO SQL 92 standard query which you can also write and use, which i totally forgot about offcource  also works with `INDEX(Cat, price)`

```
    SELECT 
     *
    FROM 
     products products_outer
    WHERE 
     2 <= (

       SELECT 
          COUNT(*) FROM products products_inner
       WHERE
          products_inner.cat = products_outer.cat
        AND 
          products_inner.price >= products_outer.price 
     )
;
```

**Result**

```
| Product | Price | Cat |
| ------- | ----- | --- |
| iPhone  | 1     | 32  |
| Samsung | 2     | 32  |
| Dell    | 1     | 21  |
| HP      | 2     | 21  |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/irCt36b5eZ2Ty6eamjcpJa/14)

**Anyhow lots of roads are headed to Rome, now find the correct one**

Comment: taking too long, have not displayed result even after 1 min, tried many times :) my table is bigger, contains more than 99999 rows.

Comment: @WasimA Post the result of. `SHOW CREATE TABLE product` ? As i doubt you created the index or indexes before running these queries which i talked about..